# Swift: Adding parameter to protocol function

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

Consider the following code, which prints `"working"` when a button is pressed:

```
protocol MyClassDelegate: class {
    func foo()
}

class MyClass {

    weak var delegate: MyClassDelegate?

    func foo() {
        delegate?.foo()
    }

    let button: UIButton = {
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(foo), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
}

class MyViewController { ... }

extension MyViewController: MyClassDelegate {
    func foo() {
        print("working")
    }
}
```

When I try adding a parameter to `MyClassDelegate`'s `foo` method, `"working"` stops printing (meaning the button stops working?). I.e.:

```
protocol MyClassDelegate: class {
    func foo(_ str: String)
}

class MyClass {

    weak var delegate: MyClassDelegate?

    func foo() {
        delegate?.foo("working")
    }

    let button: UIButton = {
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(foo), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
}

class MyViewController { ... }

extension MyViewController: MyClassDelegate {
    func foo(_ str: String) {
        print(str)
    }
}
```

How can I get the second version of the code with the parameter to work? Thanks.

Comment: What is showDetails() for ?

Comment: Whoops, C&P error. Fixed.

Comment: The second example should work in a similar way than the first one if you are assigning delegate the right way. If you have doubt that the button itself is setup correctly you can always use our beloved debug friend `print` to check that in your `foo()` method 

Comment: Turns out all I needed to do was to declare the button as a `lazy var`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `button` needs to be a declared with `lazy var` rather than with `let`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a wrong method on the  delegate . Your `MyClassDelegate` doesn't have method named `showDetails()` . Call your delegate method this way:

```
 func foo() {
    delegate?.foo("working")
  }
```

Comment: Right, I accidentally put `showDetails` instead of `foo`. My post has been updated.

Answer (score -1):

Did you do that: `cell.delegate = self` in your ViewController?