# Swift: UICollectionViewCell - Dismiss UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Trying to dismiss a slide-in `UICollectionView` by tapping a cell in the collection view. I Am able to dismiss by tapping outside of the collection view by using a dismiss function. Thanks

Update: Found the solution using a delegate. I have marked parts of the code with the solution steps.

Find my Codes below.

**HomeController:**

```
        import UIKit

class HomeController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let userInfoCell = "userInfoCell"
    let dashboardCell = "dashboardCell"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .cyan
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(mainCollectionView)
        mainCollectionView.dataSource = self
        mainCollectionView.delegate = self

        mainCollectionView.register(UserInfoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: userInfoCell)
        mainCollectionView.register(DashboardCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: dashboardCell)
    }

    let mainCollectionView: UICollectionView = {

        let windowWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let windowHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 16
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let mainCV = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        mainCV.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 20)
        mainCV.center = CGPoint(x: windowWidth - (windowWidth / 2), y: windowHeight - (windowHeight / 2))
        mainCV.backgroundColor = .red

        mainCV.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        return mainCV
    }()

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 1 {
            return 1
        }
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: dashboardCell, for: indexPath) as! DashboardCell
            cell.plusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(plusButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell
        }
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userInfoCell, for: indexPath) as! UserInfoCell
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            return CGSize(width: (view.frame.width / 3) - 30 , height: 100)
        }
        return CGSize(width: (view.frame.width / 2) - 30 , height: 200)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        if section == 1 {
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 10, right: 15)
        }
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 10, right: 15)
    }

    @objc func plusButtonPressed() {
        print("Plus button pressed")
        taggObjectLauncher.showSlideInImages()

    }

    lazy var taggObjectLauncher: SlideInViewLauncher = {
        let launcher = SlideInViewLauncher()
        launcher.homeController = self
        return launcher
    }()

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

class UserInfoCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .blue
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class DashboardCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .green
        setupDashboardViews()
    }

    func setupDashboardViews() {
        addSubview(plusButton)
    }

    let plusButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .yellow
        button.setTitle("Plus", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
        button.titleLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3) - 40, height: 90)
        return button
    }()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**SlideInViewLauncher Controller:**

```
        import UIKit

class SlideInViewLauncher: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var imageCategories: [ImageCategory]?

    var homeController = HomeController()

    var imageCell = ImageCell()

    private let cellIdentifier = "ImageCell"


    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        return cv

    }()

    let blackView = UIView()

    @objc func showSlideInImages() {

        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

            let height = CGFloat(450)
            let y = window.frame.height - height

            collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)

            collectionView.register(SlideInViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

            window.addSubview(blackView)
            window.addSubview(collectionView)
            blackView.frame = window.frame
            blackView.alpha = 0

            imageCategories = ImageCategory.sampleImageCategories()

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.blackView.alpha = 1
                self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func handleDismiss() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 0
            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
            }
        })
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected")

    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let count = imageCategories?.count {
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SlideInViewCell

        cell.imageCategory = imageCategories?[indexPath.row]

    ///////////////
    // Solution: Part 5

        cell.cellDelegate = self
    ///////////////

        return cell
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width , height: 200)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
}

    ////////////
    // Solution: Part 4

    extension SlideInViewLauncher: MyCustomCellDelegate {
    func didPressButton() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    self.blackView.alpha = 0
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
    self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(X: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: 
    self.collectionView.frame.width, height: 
    self.collectionView.frame.height)

    }
    })
    }
    }

    /////////////
```

**SlideInViewCell Controller:**

```
       import UIKit

    ////////////////
    //Solution: Part 1

protocol MyCustomCellDelegate: class {
func didPressButton()
}

   ///////////// 

class SlideInViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    /////////////////
    // Solution: Part 2

    weak var cellDelegate: MyCustomDelegate?

    ////////////////

    var homeViewController = HomeController()

    var slideInViewLauncher = SlideInViewLauncher()

    var imageCategory: ImageCategory? {
        didSet {
            if let name = imageCategory?.name {
                mainCategoryLabel.text = name
            }
        }
    }

    var image: Image?

    private let cellID = "objectCellID"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let mainCategoryLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    var slideInImagesCollectionView: UICollectionView = {

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return collectionView

    }()

    let dividerLineView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 0.4)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        addSubview(slideInImagesCollectionView)
        addSubview(dividerLineView)
        addSubview(mainCategoryLabel)

        slideInImagesCollectionView.dataSource = self
        slideInImagesCollectionView.delegate = self

        slideInImagesCollectionView.register(ImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-14-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": mainCategoryLabel]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-14-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": dividerLineView]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": slideInImagesCollectionView]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[mainCategoryLabel(30)][v0][v1(0.5)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": slideInImagesCollectionView, "v1": dividerLineView, "mainCategoryLabel": mainCategoryLabel]))
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let count = imageCategory?.images?.count {
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
        cell.image = imageCategory?.images?[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: frame.height - 30)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(35, 10, 10, 10)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let imageSelected = imageCategory!.images?[indexPath.item]
        print(imageSelected?.name ?? "Error: No item at index path")

    //////////////////
// Solution: Part 3

    cellDelegate?.didPressButton()

    //////////////////
    }
}

class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var image: Image? {
        didSet {
            if let name = image?.name {
                nameLabel.text = name
            }

            if let imageName = image?.imageName {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            }
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(imageView)
        addSubview(nameLabel)

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: 100)
        nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.width + 2, width: frame.width, height: 40)
    }
}
```

**Models Controller:**

```
        import UIKit

class ImageCategory: NSObject {

    var name: String?
    var images: [Image]?

    static func sampleImageCategories() -> [ImageCategory] {

        var someImages = [Image]()

        let someImageCategory = ImageCategory()
        someImageCategory.name = "Some Category"

        let heartImage = Image()
        heartImage.name = "Heart"
        heartImage.imageName = "heart"
        heartImage.category = "Some Category"

        someImages.append(heartImage)

        someImageCategory.images = someImages

        // Return the array of image categories:

        return [someImageCategory]
    }
}

class Image: NSObject {

    var id: NSNumber?
    var name: String?
    var category: String?
    var imageName: String?
}
```

Comment: Please read [this article about creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You've included way too much unrelated code.

Comment: I stripped the app down to just its basic func. I added everything incase someone wanted to recreate and test. Thanks

Comment: Was able to solve this by adding a delegate. Thanks to Kirill Dubovitsky answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565712/swift-add-button-to-uicollectionviewcell-that-opens-new-controller/43566008

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this by adding a delegate protocol. See comments in code. Also, sorry if my post does not quite follow protocol. This is my first post.

Thanks